# Extract distinct examples from json data in python and assign value based on json data

Tags: python, json

I have a list of json-style entries:

```
data = 

[
 {'data_1': 1, 'data_2': 1, 'key': A}, 
 {'data_1': 0, 'data_2': 1, 'key': B}, 
 {'data_1': 1, 'data_2': 0, 'key': A}
 ....
]
```

What I want to do is extract distinct examples by Key and then add value "Good" if data_1 is 0 and add value "Bad" if data_1 is has 1 anywhere in the list.

My solution right now:

1. Create `distinct = []` and `used_data = []`
2. Iterate through each item in list and extract item.key value
3. if item.key is not in used_data, append `{'key': item.key, 'value': "Good" (if item.data_1 is 0) or "Bad" (if item.data_1 is 1)}` to distinct
4. If `item.key` is already in `used_data`, iterate through distinct until you find existing key entry and change to Bad depending if you find that data_1 has equaled 1 at some point. If Value is Bad, it will never become Good. However, if value is Good, it can become Bad if data_1 is ever 1 for that Key.

Pseudocode:

```
distinct = []
used_data = []
for each in data:
    if each['key'] not in used_data:
       used_data.append(each['key'])
       if each['data_1'] = 1:
            distinct.append({'key':each.key, 'data_1': each.data_1, 'value':'Bad'})
       else:
            distinct.append({'key':each.key, 'data_1': each.data_1, 'value':'Good'})
    else:
       for every in distinct:
           if every['key'] = each['key']:
               #change every.value to Bad if each.data_1 is 1
```

The above works, but it feels very inefficient to me and I am wondering if there is a better way. Is there a json-specific function that can do some of this for me?

Comment: I did! Thank you.

Comment: For point 4 you might need to clarify. It can go from "good" to "bad" but then could it go back to "good" again? If so, a dictionary would be much better than a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just iterate once through the existing list to get the "Bad" keys and then iterate again. I'm sure there's a fancier way, but I don't think it would be any faster or more readable.

```
data = [
 {'data_1': 1, 'data_2': 1, 'key': 'A'}, 
 {'data_1': 0, 'data_2': 1, 'key': 'B'}, 
 {'data_1': 1, 'data_2': 0, 'key': 'A'}
 ]

bad_data = set([item['key'] for item in data if item['data_1'] == 1])

new_data = []
for item in data:
    item['value'] = 'Bad' if item['key'] in bad_data else 'Good'
    new_data.append(item)
```

If you don't want a new list (I'm not sure from the question), then you can modify the existing list of dicts though:

```
bad_data = set([item['key'] for item in data if item['data_1'] == 1])

for item in data:
    item['value'] = 'Bad' if item['key'] in bad_data else 'Good'
```